# How can I add xkill in the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity

I would like to add the command `xkill` to the Unity launcher so I can just click on it to kill a program. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answers to this previous thread can show you how to create a custom launcher to the Dock bar in Unity

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)